# Reading wieghted graph using python igraph from adjacency matrix

Tags: python, igraph, adjacency-matrix, weighted

I have a text file containing the adjacency matrix for my graph. Each value in the matrix corresponds to the edge weights between the respective vertex. How can I read this matrix using igraph package in python so that each edge is given its respective weight.

Answer (score 0):

since you seem to be a beginner, there is  a [python-igraph-tutorial](http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html).

You can also find the documentation there and for your specific problem you need the ['Read' method](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#Read). You need to specify a file name and probably the adjacancy parameter.